# ROOT's TMVA user guide

Tags: root-framework

I am using ROOT's TMVA (developed by CERN), the version of the ROOT is 6.24.
the user manual i have is for TMVA version 4.3.0 (for ROOT >= 6.12/00 on May 26, 2020)
but the manual seems to be a little bit different from my current version (for example, the options available for a particular machine learning model).

is there any updated user manual, or portals that provide guides on the options available for a particular machine learning model.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the same thing as you today (Planning to work on SVM machine learning method).

From a previous post of the 4th of April, see : https://root-forum.cern.ch/t/does-up-to-date-tmva-user-guide-exists/49465/2, it seems that the latest update on the TMVA user guide is the one of May 2020.

ROOT devs are saying that the latest "update" on how to use TMVA can be found on https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/group__tutorial__tmva.html (which I did not try) or the file TMVAClassification.C (https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/TMVAClassification_8C.html)

Hope you find what you want!

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your suggestion. They are really good for beginners. But for me who seek for the details explaination to the parameters (method specific), the current available documentation seems not very helpful (especially for Machine learning newbie like me)